# What does min(iterable, *[, key, default]) return

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, for-loop, min

For `df` below, I want to find the nearest datetime for a specific timestamp, which is one minute before the current timestamp, from the range of 10 values before and after the current `Timestamp`.

But I observed different values returned for `one_min_ago_data` in different cases, sometimes it returned the `Timestamp`, other times it returned the entire rows as `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`. What does `min(iterable, *[, key, default])` return? What does the `min()` function return in this case? I probably have overlooked something here but I am not sure what. Any advice appreciated.

`df`:

```
        Timestamp               A           B           C
912262  2001-02-10 00:01:45.910 45.5        NaN         zero
530129  2001-02-10 00:05:33.430 43.5        NaN         zero
243281  2001-02-10 00:07:05.600 45.0        NaN         zero
520580  2001-02-10 00:07:13.600 46.0        NaN         zero
228900  2001-02-10 00:07:23.600 47.0        NaN         zero
```

and the code I used looks something like this:

```
for i in range(1, len(df.index)):

    left_timestamp = df.loc[i - 10:i - 1]
    right_timestamp = df.loc[i + 1:i + 10]

    time_one_min_ago = df.loc[i, 'Timestamp'] - datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)

    one_min_ago_data = min(left_timestamp.append(right_timestamp).to_numpy(), key=lambda x: abs(x[timestamp_index] - time_one_min_ago))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought pandas' rolling window are perfect for this but it came with too much limitation, so we are back to some good old loops:

```py
timestamp = df['Timestamp'].to_numpy()
l = len(timestamp)
win_size = 10

result = np.empty(l, dtype='datetime64[ns]')

for i, ts in enumerate(timestamp):
    # Take 10 rows from above and 10 from below, but not the current row
    lbound = max(i-win_size, 0)
    ubound = min(i+win_size, l-1) + 1
    tmp = timestamp.take([idx for idx in range(lbound, ubound) if idx != i])
    
    # Find the timestamp with the lowest distance from the current timestamp
    argmin = np.abs(tmp - ts).argmin()
    result[i] = tmp[argmin]
    
df['result'] = result
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the solution, do you know how I can take the `A` values that correspond to the `tmp`? I want to work out their mean.